# Javascript: Array undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, scripting, photoshop, extendscript

Sorry if this question was already asked. I found undefined errors but not for array so heres my question:

I get an 'undefined is not an object' error when im trying to declare selRef41 with the given Array. 
(btw Im using ESTK and i am writing this script for Photoshop)

```
var docRef = app.activeDocument;
var layRef = docRef.activeLayer;

function createSelection(layRef) {
// Declare function variables
const oneT = 1/3;
const twoT = (1/3)*2;

docRef = app.activeDocument;
layRef = app.activeLayer;

if (detailFactor == "2x2") {
    var selRef41 = Array(Array(0, 0),
                        Array(layRef.width.value / 2, 0),
                        Array(layRef.width.value / 2, layRef.height.value / 2),
                        Array(0, layRef.height.value / 2));
}
```

The corresponding main is just a one-liner to call the function:

```
function main() {
createSelection(layRef);
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the actual error it's a bit hard to pinpoint but I'm guessing it's either `app` or `layRef` which is `undefined`. You should indent your code as well so it's easier to read.

Comment: The Error 'undefined as an object' occurs exactly at the line (var selRef41 = Array..). Sorry I forgot to mention that. Does this help to kinda pinpoint the error down?
Ive tried defining `layRef` above the function. `app` shouldnt be a problem tho, because i could also leave it out (tested in ESTK).

Comment: Check app.activeLayer in your function - does it have a value?

Comment: If I let Photoshop alert ´app.activeLayer´ it says its the currently selected. I used ´layRef.bounds[3]-layRef.bounds[1]´ now to get the height and ´parseInt´ to get rid of the px ending,But now Im getting an error at ´layRef.selection.select(selRef41)´ . Same error as above, but it should be defined

Comment: I don't think the ArtLayer object has a width or height property (going from memory here, so you should check the Photoshop Scripting Reference). On an unrelated note, `layRef = app.activeLayer;` should be `layRef = docRef.activeLayer;`

Comment: perhaps test to see if layRef and docRef are valid before building the array, e.g. `if app.activeDocument && app.activeLayer){ … }`

Answer (score 0):

Where did you find this `layRef.width.value`? Layers don't have `width` or `height` property (only documents have), this is the thing that causes error in your code. You can calculate width and height using their `bounds`:

```
var layRef = docRef.activeLayer;
refWidth = layRef.bounds[2] - layRef.bounds[0];
refheight = layRef.bounds[3] - layRef.bounds[1];
alert([refWidth,refheight]);
```

You can check [Photoshop Scripting Reference pdf](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-javascript-ref-2015.pdf) to check properties and methods of DOM objects.

Also, as cybernetic.nomad noted, this won't work: `layRef = app.activeLayer;`, and plus you have `if (detailFactor == "2x2")` but `detailFactor` wan't assigned.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning, Ive added the parts you and cybernetic.nomad suggested and it worked.
Although using bounds wasnt exactly what I wanted to achieve with getting only parts of the layers height and width, so Ive just opened the file in a new document and edited it there, save the data in an Array and that worked out fine.
`detailFactor` was declared as a global variable, sorry!

Comment: I wonder, what scenario did you have so bounds were giving your only parts of w and h?